# Remove item in nested object mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to remove items from an array with the use of mongoose, this is my code.

```
const { ids } = req.body;
  try {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate('user', 'name').exec();
    if (!order) {
      return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Vous ne pouvez pas fermer une commande déjà fermée' }] });
    }
    order.status = 'Partial';
    if (ids) {
      for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 1) {
        const e = ids[i];
        // @ts-ignore
        order.products[e] = undefined;
      }
    }
    console.log(order);
    const changedOrder = await order.save();
    res.json(changedOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Server Error' }] });
  }
```

When I log it to the console the item in updated object is removed but it doesn't save in MongoDB when using .save().

When I was using delete order.products[e], it did the same thing.

Is there a way to update it with findbyidandupdate instead of modifying it in the memory?

Comment: you want to remove all data in products like `J78OR5RUybLp6ysn475WU` object?

Comment: yes completely remove it from the parent object "products"

Comment: after update use want to have doc like this ?
`_id,user,status, ... , product : {}` ?

Comment: I want to have the same structure as now, I want to simply remove one or several key: value pairs from "products"

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove all object in `products`
use this

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    products: {}
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/aBSnpRhblxt

if you want to delete specific key (gCx5qSTLvdWeel8E2Yo7m) from product use this

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $unset: {
    "products.gCx5qSTLvdWeel8E2Yo7m": undefined
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/z6xRyh3oJrs

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Mohammad but I think this works for MongoDB, but in mongoose, we need to set the value as 1 to remove the item with unset.

Here is my working example

```js
const { ids } = req.body;
  try {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate('user', 'name').exec();
    if (!order) {
      return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Vous ne pouvez pas fermer une commande déjà fermée' }] });
    }
    console.log(ids);
    const un: {
      [key:string]: number,
    } = {};
    if (ids) {
      for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 1) {
        const e = ids[i];
        un[`products.${e}`] = 1;
      }
    }
    console.log(un);
    const changedOrder = await Order.updateOne({ id: req.params.id }, {
      $unset: un,
    }, { new: true }).populate('user', 'name');
    console.log(changedOrder);
    res.json(changedOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Server Error' }] });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I did and it wasn't working in mongoose.

Comment: there is no error, when i was in debug session, mongoose doesn't even run $unset if the value update is set to undefined.

Comment: change `undefind` to another value , to see update function could change value or not

Comment: could you log output of mongoose out put